# Xcode Enum woes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enums

I thought I had this sorted, but I am still missing something.

Very simply, I have a Settings class that hold a DAO (sitting on a plist).  I want to have a couple of enums for the settings for convenience and readability, such as GamePlayType and DifficultyLevel.  Right now I am defining them in the Settings.h file above the @interface line as such:

```
typedef enum {
 EASY,
 NORMAL,
 HARD
} DifficultyLevel;
```

and

```
typedef enum {
 SET_NUMBER_OF_MOVES,
 TO_COMPLETION
} GamePlayType;
```

If I access them from within the Settings class like:

```
- (int)gridSizeForLOD {
 switch ([self difficultyLevel]) {
  case EASY:
   return GRID_SIZE_EASY;
  case NORMAL:
   return GRID_SIZE_NORMAL;
  case HARD:
   return GRID_SIZE_HARD;
  default:
   return GRID_SIZE_NORMAL;
 }
}
```

everything is fine.

But, if I try to access them outside of the Settings class, let's say in my main view controller class, like this:

```
if (([settings gameType] == SET_NUMBER_OF_MOVES) && (numMoves == [settings numMovesForLOD])) {
    [self showLoseScreen];
}
```

I get errors (like EXC_BAD_ACCESS) or the condition always fails.  Am I doing something incorrectly?

Also, I should point out that I have this code for the call to gameType (which lives in the Settings class):

```
- (GamePlayType)gameType {
    return [dao gameType];
}
```

and the DAO implements gameType like this:

```
- (int)gameType {
    return (settingsContent != nil) ? [[settingsContent objectForKey:@"Game Type"] intValue] : 0;
}
```

I know I have the DAO returning an int instead of a GamePlayType, but A) the problem I am describing arose there when I tried to use the "proper" data type, and B) I did not think it would matter since the enum is just a bunch of named ints, right?

Any help, greatly appreciated.  I really want to understand this thoroughly, and something is eluding me...

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: The backtrace you get from the debugger after the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception should give you a lot of information about the problem.  The code you've shown here doesn't have any obvious problems.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS smells like a problem unrelated to enums in every way. I'd look elsewhere. Set breakpoints, and as Carl Norum said, look at the backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have it there already you'll need an import like below in your other class

```
#import "Settings.h"
```